# How to display variables on a new line python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a small app using tkinter. Part of my code looks like this:

```
weatherinfo = str(z + y + x + w + v + u)
info = Label(mainwindow, bg = 'magenta', height = 8, width = 14, text = weatherinfo, font = ('arial', 20, 'normal'))
info.pack(side = LEFT,padx = 20)
```

I'm trying to get each variable (x,y, Etc.) to be displayed on a new line in my label called info. However, they're all printing out on one line. How can I fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: I had tried something along those lines but was unsuccessful, but your version worked. Solved, thank you very much.

Comment: Cool. I'll convert my comment to an answer so can accept it and close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inserting the newlines into the weatherinfo string?

```
weatherinfo = '\n'.join([z, y, x, w, v, u])
```